# Need to convert to ICollection

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to convert this code (see code comment) to ICollection but there is no ToList() method.

```
// GET: api/Students
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetStudents()
{            
    var resultOfQuery = from s in _context.Students
                        join sc in _context.StudentCourses on s.StudentId equals sc.StudentId
                        join c in _context.Courses on sc.CourseId equals c.CourseId
                        select new Student
                        {
                            StudentId = s.StudentId,
                            Lname = s.Lname,
                            StudentCourses = new StudentCourse { Course = new Course { CourseTitle = c.CourseTitle, CreatedDt = c.CreatedDt } } // This is the code I need help with
                        };
    return await resultOfQuery.ToListAsync();
}
```

This is the error:
 `Cannot implicitly convert type 'StudentAPI.Models.StudentCourse' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<StudentAPI.Models.StudentCourse>'`

These are my models

```
public class Student 
{
    public Student()
    {
        StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
    
// Intermediate Table
public partial class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDt { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; } = null!;
}
//

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

For `ICollection<StudentCourse>`, I only needed the list of courses each student is enrolled in

Comment: You should initialize the property like this :`StudentCourses = new List<StudentCourse>{ new StudentCourse { Course = new Course { CourseTitle = c.CourseTitle, CreatedDt = c.CreatedDt } }}`

Comment: Oh shoot. Thanks for pointing that our Eldar. If you could submit your answer below, I would mark it as the answer

Comment: They way you have the `join`s setup, you are creating a new `Student` object for every `Course` they belong to, instead of one `Student` object with multiple courses in `StudentCourses`. In general, you shouldn't be using `join` with EF (are you using EF?) anyway - you should use navigation properties and relationships.

Comment: @Eldar that will not accomplish the correct result. If you are having to manually create a singleton `List<T>`, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @NetMage Thanks bud. Will look into that. I'm using EF

Comment: Your query seems to have a problem relative to your query - you reference `CreatedDt` which doesn't appear in `Course`?

Comment: When done, your query should be something like `var resultOfQuery = _context.Students.Include(s => s.StudentCourses).ThenInclude(sc => sc.Course);`.

Comment: @NetMage That's much shorter and look cleaner. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Thats because your data class have virtual collection of StudentCourse(**ICollection**) and in LINQ query you trying to tell that one single entity(**StudentCourse**) is **collection**. As Eldar said you need to create List instead of single entity

Comment: Yep stupid mistake